# Regex pattern to match file version

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match the Major, Minor, Revision and the Build number.

My problem is:

given 2 Versions

```
string Version1 = "01.01.02.44";
string Version2 = "01.01.02.FF1";
string pattern =@"\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+";
var regEx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var versionMatch = regEx.Match(Version2);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                 // DO ...
            }
```

Using the following regex pattern :

```
string pattern =@"\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+";
```

I can match Version1...

But how would i make it match Version2 ?

Comment: You need to give more examples. Explain the rules for valid and invalid version numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check for whatever characters are valid in your version number and not just digits. eg the following regex will match both:

```
string pattern =@"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.[0-9F]+";
```

This matches on the assumption that the first three parts are all purely numeric whereas the last one can be any number or the letter F. You would just modify the character class as appropriate to match your precise requirements (which we don't know).

Comment: Oops. That'll teach me to copy and paste the OPs thing and just modify the obvious errors. Will update. ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak: That is true but still no excuse. :)

Comment: Thanks ...this is what i needed..i was just asking myself if i had to worry about being the revision number Hex...but this solves the problem

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach is to split on `.`.

```
string[] parts = versionNumber.Split('.');
if (parts.Length != 4)
{
    // Invalid revision number.
}
else
{
    string major = parts[0];
    string minor = parts[1];
    string revision = parts[2];
    string buildNumber = parts[3];
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Sure, if the OP is trying to get the parts of the version. I don't think that's the case.

Answer (score 3):

Why use string manipulations to handle version numbers ?

I recommend using the **System.Version** class.

That class already manages all parts of a version (*Build*, *Major*, *MajorRevision*, *Minor*, *MinorRevision*, *Revision*).

You can easily compare version numbers, not only for a match, but also to check if a version number is older or newer than another :

```
Version v1 = new Version(2, 0);
Version v2 = new Version("2.1");

Console.Write("Version {0} is ", v1);

switch(v1.CompareTo(v2))
{
   case 0:
      Console.Write("the same as");
      break;
   case 1:
      Console.Write("later than");
      break;
   case -1:
      Console.Write("earlier than");
      break;
}

Console.WriteLine(" Version {0}.", v2);
```

Take a look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) about System.Version for more details and examples.

That class will save you the overhead of handling the different parts of a version number yourself using string manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

thats because you are only looking for integers 0-9 and not for letters

you can split the sting into multiple groups, use the .*? to get all characters instead only the [0-9]

```
 @"(?s)\.(?<string>.*?)\.(?<string>.*?)\.(?<string>.*?)\.(?<string>.*?)"
```

Comment: You have successfully replicated OP's bug ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To capture both strings you mention you can change:

```
string pattern =@"\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+";
```

to:

```
string pattern =@"\d\d[.]\d\d[.]\d\d[.]...|\d\d[.]\d\d[.]\d\d[.]..";
```

It would be good for you to learn a little about how regex works though and maybe test a few scenarios out.  Then you can tweak the pattern to match your exact needs.

If you want to capture a dot (.) in yuor pattern you have to enclose it in square brackets because it is used as a reserved character.  The plus (+) means any number of the preceding character, so \d+ will match any number of digits (01 and 0123 and 567789 etc).

See [regex cheat sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v1/png/).

If you want to test out your regular expression you can do it [online](http://regexpal.com/).